# What's the code page of UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8

My command prompt's default code page is 936.

I need to change it to UTF-8.

```
chcp 65001
```

The above doesn't work. What's the correct one?

Comment: chcp 65001 worked nice for me. Programs that are not utf-8 will output a big mess, of course.

Comment: Did you try non ascii letters?

Answer (score 13):

In order for `chcp 65001` to work, you must be using a TrueType font in the command prompt. One such font is Lucida Console.

To use Lucida Console:

- Right click on the window title bar
- Select `Properties`
- Select the tab `Font`
- Select `Lucida Console`
- Press `OK`

Comment: Unfortunately neither Lucida Console, nor Consolas seem to render non-ASCII characters correctly in the command-prompt (which makes me really nervous about handling files with such characters). `:-(`

Comment: Oops, nevermind. It renders correctly (Chrome messed up the Unicode characters when it created the `.URL` file). My concern about how files with Unicode characters in their names stands. I worry that performing operations like copy or move would not work or worse, mess things up. I tried using the `chcp` command it complained about being unable to write to the device. I tried it again without the command and it worked. `o.O`

Comment: @Synetech don't worry, the display is wrong, the characters are correct. `cd ű` is displayed at `cd ?`, but it still goes into the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Many people complain in different questions about the `65001` support in windows console. My particular solution was to use ISO-8859-1 code page (28591) instead of UTF-8. You might take a look at the [Code Page Identifiers at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) to identify one that fits your character needs.